# Two ways of writing the same query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using northwind database and I've written a query that decreases a `Quantity` by 20% and set `Discount` to given value:

```
update dbo.[Order Details]
set Quantity = round(0.8 * Quantity, 0), Discount = 0.5
where exists (
    select *
    from dbo.Orders o
    where o.OrderID = dbo.[Order Details].OrderID and
    o.OrderDate > '1997-05-15'
)
select * from dbo.[Order Details]
```

It seems to be working just fine. I decided to try to do the same thing using `join` instead of binding two tables in `where`. I came up with this:

```
update dbo.[Order Details]
set Quantity = round(0.8 * Quantity, 0), Discount = 0.4
where exists (
    select *
    from dbo.Orders o join dbo.[Order Details] od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    where o.OrderDate > '1997-05-15'
)
select * from dbo.[Order Details]
```

This query changes EVERY record in `[Order Details]` table - which appears weird to me, since subquery selects records on the same condition the first query did.
Why do those two work in a different way?

**EDIT:**
This query seems to do what I wanted and what the first query does.

```
    update dbo.[Order Details]
    set Quantity = round(0.8 * Quantity, 0), Discount = 0.1
    where OrderID in (
        select o.OrderID
        from dbo.Orders o inner join dbo.[Order Details] od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
        where o.OrderDate > '1997-05-15'
    )
    select * from dbo.[Order Details]
```

Comment: The first query has a correlated subquery, the second one updates everything if a single order with at lease one detail had an OrderDate after the date specified. (Short version: the queries do not have the same conditions.)

Comment: MySQL != T-SQL, don't spam tags

Comment: @Uueerdo I see what you meant with the second query and now I don't get it why the first version doesn't work this way - I use `exists` in it as well.

Comment: It is not `exists` causing the issue, the first query's subquery is `correlated` with on `o.OrderID = od.OrderID`; that means it is effectively though inefficiently "joining" to the outer query. The second query's subquery is self-contained.

Comment: Your third query's subquery doesn't actually need to have a join in it; it should be able to just query the `Orders` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be your 3rd version is using update from over inner join.. SQL Server

```
update d
set Quantity = round(0.8 * Quantity, 0), Discount = 0.5
from dbo.[Order Details] d
inner join dbo.Orders o
    on o.OrderID = d.OrderID
where
   o.OrderDate > cast('1997-05-15' as date)
```

Comment: everything works.. but you have not tried update from and could be the fastest if you are using sql server